# Equivalente de peticion curl en visual .net

Tags: vb.net, .net, curl

Como estan , estoy tratando de usar el servicio de watson , el cual hace una peticion post a una url , y el codigo curl es el siguiente, quisiera saber como podría hacer el equivalente de esta petición en visual .net con visual basic de lenguaje.

```
curl -X POST -u "{username}":"{password}" —-header "Content-Type:application/json" --data "{\"input\": {\"text\": \"Turn on the lights\"}, \"context\": {\"conversation_id\": \"1b7b67c0-90ed-45dc-8508-9488bc483d5b\", \"system\": {\"dialog_stack\": [\"root\"], \"dialog_turn_counter\": 1, \"dialog_request_counter\": 1}}}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/25dfa8a0-0263-471b-8980-317e68c30488/message?version=2016-09-20"
```

Comment: Revisa esta respuesta para C#
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929013/making-a-curl-call-in-c-sharp
te puede ser util

Answer (score 2):

`curl` es una herramienta de línea de comandos que hace una petición REST a un servicio, en tu caso Watson pero en principio sobre cualquier servicio REST.

Para hacerlo desde Visual Basic o C# tienes que utilizar librerías que realicen este tipo de llamadas o hacerlas tú mismo.

Aunque encontrarás muchas información sobre el tema, puedes empezar con este artículo de [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/497123/How-to-make-REST-requests-with-Csharp).

Existen varias librerías de REST para .Net, entre ellas quizá la más utilizada sea [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/).